# Python mock os.environ used inside a class

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I'm trying to mock `os.environ` inside a class but I just can't get it right. Here's my structure:

```
#file.py
import os

class MyClass():
    connection_url = os.environ['DB']

#some code
```

And here's my test (latest try, anyways):

```
#test.py
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch
from file import MyClass

class TestMyClass(TestCase):
    @patch.dict('file.os.environ', {'DB' : 'Dummy' })
    def setUp(self):
         self.class = MyClass()

#some testing
```

This is failing miserably, raising KeyError 'DB'... Can someone help me? I'm new to python unittesting. I researched some blogs and stackoverflow, tried some solutions but couldn't get it right.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that `connection_url` is set when the class is created (at import time).  If you want to mock it, you can patch the attribute on the class itself before you *use* that attribute:

```
class TestMyClass(TestCase):
    @patch.object(file.MyClass, 'connection_url', 'Dummy')
    def setUp(self):
        self.instance = MyClass()
```

You'll still have to deal with the potential `KeyError` at import time -- i.e. you'll need to make sure that your test runner has a dummy value in the environment before you *import file* or else you'll have to modify the code in `file.py` to make sure that it doesn't raise a `KeyError`.  There are a few strategies here.  You can just suppress the `KeyError` letting `connection_url = default_value` if it wasn't set in the environment:

```
class MyClass():
    connection_url = os.environ.get('DB', default_value)
```

Or you can move the connection_url fetching into `__init__`:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        connection_url = os.environ['DB']
```

This latter code has the additional benefit that your `patch.dict` should start to work.

Note that if you choose the either of the first two approaches, the instance will only have the patched `connection_url` during the `setUp` method -- The subsequent tests won't have that patched.  It's quite likely that this will be a show-stopper and you'll need to create a new instance in each test that you have:

```
class TestMyClass(TestCase):
    @patch.object(file.MyClass, 'connection_url', 'Dummy')
    def test_first_thing(self):
        self.instance = MyClass()
        ...

    @patch.object(file.MyClass, 'connection_url', 'Dummy')
    def test_second_thing(self):
        self.instance = MyClass()
        ...
```

Comment: I think this is patching the wrong place, because `os.environ['DB']` will still be accessed (and possibly `KeyError` if not configured in test env).  I mean, the OP code is raising at import time not at setup time, so the patch is not going to help that.

Comment: @wim -- Absolutely.  The problem is that you _can't_ really patch something at import time.  All you can do is patch the object when you intend to _use_ it.  This will replace whatever value `connection_url` happens to have with the dummy value that OP wants.  As you point out, it doesn't prevent a `KeyError` if `'DB'` isn't in the environment -- The only way around that is to _set_ `os.environ` _before importing_ any code, or by modifying the non-test code ...

Comment: Hence this answer is not really useful.  Once any test method tries to use the `self.instance`, an old `connection_url` would be restored.  I don't see any point of patching in the `setUp`.  With the code we've been shown it will require either a different approach, or a restructure of the class.

Comment: @wim -- That depends critically on _where_ and how `connection_url` is used on the class.  e.g. if `self.connection_url` is only used in `__init__` (which might actually be reasonable), then this would be a fine way to set up a fake connection on each test on the class.

Comment: @wim -- I've edited this again to hopefully give more clarity around what is happening and the various options to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the enlightment, @mgilson!